# Do any Oneworld loyalty programs allow retrospective miles/points claims for a non-member at time of travel?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs, oneworld

I had some flights on Cathay Pacific recently that I would like to claim miles/points for retrospectively. As Marco Polo Club of Cathay charges a 100 USD membership fee, I will not use that program.

While I had planned to register and collect e.g. with BA Executive Club, I realise now that they [require me to have been a member already at the time of travel](https://naprepin.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4453/~/claiming-missing-avios-and-tier-points-for-past-flights%2Fother-transactions--), which I was not. [Similar applies to Finnair Plus.](https://www.finnair.com/de/gb/finnair-plus/my-finnair-plus/missing-points/add-points)

So are there any other Oneworld loyalty programs that would allow me to register and claim miles for a CX flight before my membership?

Comment: For miles collecting (rather than accruing status benefits) you don't need to join Marco Polo club, just AsiaMiles (which is free). However, I don't know if it allows retro claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about American Airlines?
https://www.aa.com/i18nForward.do?locale=en_GB&p=/AAdvantage/requestingMiles.jsp

Or Iberia?
https://www.iberia.com/gb/iberiaplus/not-shown-avios/

I would not recommend Qantas as it is one of the worst programs (they even try to charge some people to join) and ask a lot of miles for award flights.

Iberia Avios are transferable to BA. BA also has a household pooling option: https://www.flystein.com/biggest-mistake-frequent-flyers-make/

Comment: It is not at all clear whether e.g. Iberia allows retrospective crediting for flights taken on another airline before joining their Iberia Plus program.

Comment: Yes, they don't explain it but it is worth to try. And what it you think about AA (which is probably best program in Oneworld besides BA)?

Comment: I am not sure about AA but with Iberia it is indeed possible to claim Avios (and Elite Points as well I assume). From email exchange with them (and similarly on the phone): *"As the Iberia Plus program general conditions establish, the deadline to claim the Avios is 6 months after the day of the flight. Also, for new accounts, we can only register the Avios for flights that were taken within 3 months before the date of registration."*

Comment: I get a much better return with Iberia than AA and it is now clear I can claim for the flights in my case. Once I receive the points I shall place a bounty on this answer, do remind me if I haven't done so within 2 months time.

Comment: Great! Could you accept my answer as the best answer? I am curious how it works here.

Answer (score 5):

Depends how far back, but members of [Australian Frequent Flyer](https://www.australianfrequentflyer.com.au/community/threads/flights-booked-before-joining-ff.18002/) group claim that Qantas, a member of OneWorld, allow you to claim for flights up to 30 days before joining.

This is backed up on an article on [Australian Business Traveller](https://www.ausbt.com.au/how-to-claim-missing-qantas-frequent-flyer-points-after-flying).